# Access methods in electron's main process from render process after building

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge, node-sqlite3

Alright so I have these methods in my index.js main process that I want to access from the render process. I have tried two ways to go about this process.

## ipcMain and ipcRender

The first idea was to use ipcMain and ipcRender using an "on" and "sendSync" The error I get back is "an object could not be cloned"

#### Index.js - Main Process

```
      ipcMain.on( "getData", ( event, callBack ) => {
        db = new sqlite3.Database(
          dbPath,
          sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, 
          function(error) { 
            if(error){
                log.error(`exception: ${error}`);
                //throw error
                if (callBack) callBack(error);
            }
            data.getModel(db, log, function(rawDataStr) {
                if (callBack) callBack(rawDataStr);
            })
          }
        )
        return db
      } );
```

#### App.Js - Render Process

```
    window.require('electron').ipcRenderer.sendSync( "getData",function(rawData){
      if (rawData.name && rawData.name == 'Error') {
        alert('PRT DB is not present');
      } else {
        sharedObj.rawData = rawData;
        app.advanceReadiness();
      }
    })
```

## @electron/remote

The other solution I tried was to use [@electron/remote](https://github.com/electron/remote).  I understand the remote module was depreciated, but I was willing to try it. This works when I run the the app locally, but as soon as I build the app with electron-forge it can no longer find my global variable.

#### Index.js - Main Process

```
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
      global.sharedObj = {
        getData:function(callBack){ 
          db = new sqlite3.Database(
            dbPath,
            sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, 
            function(error) { 
              if(error){
                  log.error(`exception: ${error}`);
                  //throw error
                  if (callBack) callBack(error);
              }
              data.getModel(db, log, function(rawDataStr) {
                  if (callBack) callBack(rawDataStr);
              })
            }
          )
        }
      }
```

#### App.js - Render Process

```
    var sharedObj = window.require('@electron/remote').getGlobal('sharedObj');
    sharedObj.getData(function (rawData) {
      if (rawData.name && rawData.name == 'Error') {
        alert('PRT DB is not present');
      } else {
        sharedObj.rawData = rawData;
        app.advanceReadiness();
      }
    });
```

Comment: I haven't used sqlite with electron, does `new sqlite3.Database` create a connection to the database or are you executing a query?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your DB connection isn't cloneable, because this DB object doesn't fit one of the valid values that can be serialized by IPC (inter-process communication). (See [this section](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#parameter--error--return-type-support) to see what we can pass between renderer > main process without issue).

You probably need to do something like this. I'm not familiar with using sqlite3 in JS, but this should hopefully get you started on the right track. The general *gist* is that you should store a *reference* to your DB in your **main.js** file and then set up a listener that listens for requests from your front-end page. Once a message is sent to the **main.js** file (ie. backend), you will query your DB, and then return the results to the front-end by sending an IPC message back (`win.webContents.send("fromMain", data);` in the example elow).

**main.js**

```js
const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
    ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;
let db = new sqlite3.Database(
    dbPath,
    sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE,
    function (error) {
        if (error) {
            log.error(`exception: ${error}`);
            //throw error
            if (callBack) callBack(error);
        }
        data.getModel(db, log, function (rawDataStr) {
            if (callBack) callBack(rawDataStr);
        })
    }
);

async function createWindow() {

    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
            contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
            enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
        }
    });

    // Load app
    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));

    // rest of code..
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
    db.retrieveData().then(data => {

        // Send result back to renderer process
        win.webContents.send("fromMain", data);
    });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
            console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
        });
        window.api.send("toMain", "some data");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```